# How to pass the product id dynamically to the Django view?

Tags: django, django-views

How to change `(id=3)` automatically? When I click on a product to get a detailed view, the slug in the url is correct, but the displayed data doesn't match.

views.py works fine:

```
def product_detail_view(request, slug_text):
    obj = Product.objects.get(id=3)
    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, 'store/product.html', context)
```

urls.py works fine:

```
urlpatterns = [
       path('<slug:slug_text>/', views.product_detail_view, name ="product"),
]
```

Comment: why are you filtering by id and not by slug

Comment: You're right. This is supposed to be the solution. However when I change the line to `obj = Product.objects.filter(id=request.user.id, slug=slug_text)` the product data disappears for some reason. In my html I still use for example `{{object.price}}` for the price tag.

Comment: why are you filtering with id=request.user.id

Comment: Aw sorry. That was a mistake. I'm just trying to see the data on my product page.